# $cordovaFileTransfer removing/ Deleting Local file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Is $cordovaFileTransfer capable of removing/deleting file in Local,I already use it  for downloading, my problem now is , i want to delete old file, before downloading the new one,if it is capable can you give some example links on how i will implement it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use remove method of file entry.

You can use the following codes :

```
function removeFile(){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUrl, gotFileRemove, function(error){});
}

function gotFileRemove(entry){
    entry.remove(function(file){
    },function(error){
        });
    }
```

Comment: what is the value of  the parameter in gotFileRemove(),

Comment: It is the file entry object.You have to only call the removeFile() method.Also replace the fileUrl with actual file url.

Comment: so @Homen , what you mean in this code is i just put the file url and then the code will automatically remove the file , correct me if im worng

Comment: Thanks !! :) @Homen